# If VBScript quits early, communicate with VBA to end VBA script early

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, sap-gui

I have some VBA code that calls on VBScript code to run an SAP GUI export:

```
'VBA CODE

'Grab date modified before running export
tstamp = FileDateTime("exportFilePath")

'Call .vbs file for SAP GUI export and pass shift variable to .vbs file

Shell "wscript """ & "filepath.vbs" & Shift & " " & DateOffset, vbNormalFocus

'Wait for export file to update before opening
X = 1
newtstamp = FileDateTime("exportFilePath")
Do While tstamp = newtstamp
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    newtstamp = FileDateTime("exportFilePath")
    X = X + 1
    If X = 60 Then 'allow 60 seconds for export 1 to complete before exiting script
        MsgBox ("Export 1 took over 60 seconds and failed to complete, try again!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop
```

In certain cases, the VBScript will be ended early (user not signed into SAP GUI, etc.)

```
'VBScript

On Error Resume Next 

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Error number of zero means no error
    MsgBox ("Error! Log into SAP then try again.")
    wscript.Quit
End If
```

In cases like this, I would like to be able to communicate to VBA that the VBScript ended early. Doing this would allow the VBA code to end before the allotted 60 seconds built into the Do Loop.

Thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: You could call [SAPGUI automation](https://codezentrale.de/sap-sap-gui-scripting-per-vba/) directly from VBA.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58348742/11636588 can help You in some case.

Comment: @Storax Fair enough, I was doing this originally, but wanted both scripts to run simultaneously to optimize run time. Might just have to go back to this strategy

Comment: If you want to run it as a script, don't display a `Msgbox` with the error. Write it in an output file (can be a text file). In your VBA code: once the script execution is completed, check the text file for any errors

Comment: Then maybe you might need to go for a solution with VB.NET where you could use threading. But that is a completely different approach.

Comment: What about adding some code into your VB script's error trap that causes the file to be emptied (overwritten with a blank file). The modified date would change, causing your VBA loop to end early.You could then test the filelength for instance, to see if the script was a success and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @Zac I like this idea and am currently trying it out. Thanks!

Comment: @CLR this is probably better than the .txt idea. Think I might go with this one. Appreciate it!

Comment: @CLR works great except for one thing. Sometimes the export file from SAP (with data) will be smaller than a blank spreadsheet created by VBScript. This doesn't make any sense to me. Here is my VBS code for overwriting the file.            `code`xls = "filepath.xlsx"  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add oBook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False o Book.SaveAs xls oBook.Close oExcel.Quit Set oExcel = Nothing Set oBook = Nothing

Comment: The 'empty' file should always be the same size though, just test for whatever that is.